# How to get all filters and functions available in Twig templates?

Tags: 8, theming

I have an option to create and edit twig templates via UI but I need to display what filters and functions are available to the user but I don't know how to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From procedural code:

```
\Drupal::service('twig')->getFilters();
\Drupal::service('twig')->getFunctions();
```

Unless the Twig service is overridden this is calling the methods on the vendor `Twig_Environment` class.

For OO code you should inject the Twig service into your class. https://drupal.org/node/2133171 and https://drupal.org/node/2203931 have some documentation and examples on how to do that.