# How can I list all Twig functions and filters with their description?

Tags: 8, theming

I want a list of all available Twig filters and functions and for each one of them I need to have a description of the function/filter so the user can see what functions and filters are available and how to use them in templates.

I know how to get the list of functions and filters([How to get all filters and functions available in Twig templates?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110672/how-to-get-all-filters-and-functions-available-in-twig-templates)) but I don't know how to get their descriptions.

I don't know how to find out in which file the filter/function resides so I can parse it for the description of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/class/TwigExtension/8 Twig functions have no descriptions. You can run `getCallable` on a twig function/filter object and then do `$reflection = new \ReflectionFunction($callable); $doxygen = $reflection->getDocComment()` to get the doxygen which is the closest to "description".